# C# XNA Perlin Noise, Array out of bounds

Tags: c#, xna, indexoutofboundsexception, perlin-noise

So, after studying this: [Wikipedia on Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#Pseudocode), I attempted to do a Class that generates a perlin noise texture (outputted as a Color[,] which would later be transformed into a texture). However, once I make it run, in all runs I get an out of bounds exception. Here's the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;


namespace Noise
{
class PerlinNoise : Noise
{
    private float[,,] gradient;
    private float[,] noise;
    private bool generated;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Width of the perlin noise</param>
    /// <param name="y">Height of the perlin noise</param>
    public PerlinNoise(int width, int height)
    {
        gradient = new float[width,height,2];

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < height; o++)
            {
                for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++)
                {
                    gradient[i, o, p] = ((float)r.NextDouble() * 2f) -1;
                }
            }
        }

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        noise = new float[width, height];
        generated = false;


    }



    float Lerp(float a0, float a1, float w)
    {
        return (1.0f - w) * a0 + w * a1;
    }

    float DotGridGradient(int ix, int iy, float x, float y)
    {
        float dx = x - (float)ix;
        float dy = y - (float)iy;


        return (dx * gradient[iy, ix, 0]) + (dy * gradient[iy, ix, 1]); //It blows up here, usually with either iy or ix = -1
    }

    public float GenerateValue(float x, float y)
    {

        int x0 = x > 0.0f ? (int)x : (int)x - 1;
        int x1 = x0 + 1;
        int y0 = y > 0.0f ? (int)y : (int)y - 1;
        int y1 = y0 + 1;

        float sx = x - (float)x0;
        float sy = y - (float)y0;

        float n0, n1, ix0, ix1, value;
        n0 = DotGridGradient(x0, y0, x, y);
        n1 = DotGridGradient(x1, y0, x, y);
        ix0 = Lerp(n0, n1, sx);
        n0 = DotGridGradient(x0, y1, x, y);
        n1 = DotGridGradient(x1, y1, x, y);
        ix1 = Lerp(n0, n1, sx);
        value = Lerp(ix0, ix1, sy);

        return value;

    }

    public Color GenerateColor(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!generated) GenerateNoise();

        Color c = new Color();
        c.R = c.G = c.B = (byte)(256 * noise[x,y]);
        return c;
    }

    public Color[,] GenerateTexture()
    {
        if (!generated) GenerateNoise();

        Color[,] color = new Color[width,height];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                color[x, y] = GenerateColor(x, y);
            }


        }

        return color;
    }

    public void GenerateNoise()
    {
        for (int x =0; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                noise[x, y] = GenerateValue(x, y);


        generated = true;
    }

}
}
```

So, what could I modify in order to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the out-of-bounds exception occur?

Comment: It is commented in the code where it occurs... But it's on the return line of the DotGridGradient method.

Comment: Sorry, I did have a quick look through for it, didn't spot it >_<

Comment: it looks that somewhere your loop goes over limit. check loops, as you start from 0 so end value should be end-1... i guess it's some problem like that.

Comment: the problem is in the opposite end. For some reason, the variables with the array coordinates start with a negative value...

Answer (score 0):

At `n1` you pass `x1` and `x`. if `x` is zero then `x0` is -1.
Then you do in the method `DotGridGradient` you set `dx`to `x0` - `x`, which is in this case -1 - 0.
Same goes for the y.
That's what the error causes.
If you begin at 1 in the for loops generating it everything is fine. I don't know anything about Perlin Noises, so I can't help you further.

Comment: Yeah, that's whats happen... The thing is that I'm starting understanding it though, it seems that perlin noise values should range between 0 and 1, and not with it's coordinates... Gotta rewrite the implementation, I guess...